# Baloo file extractor process eating all my CPU

Tags: gnome, kde, baloo

I'm on ubuntu `20.04 x86`.
Sometimes, a process called `baloo file extractor` appears and eat all my CPU ressource, making my system beeing slow.

Upon research, it seems to be  a file indexer for KDE plasma.
Why does it appears on my ubuntu which use gnome ?

Comment: Have you looked at your system logs to see when it was installed?  It's not on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop install; ie. https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/current/focal-desktop-amd64.manifest will show an *amd64* manifest where you won't find it there..  (*thus won't exist on a clean install*)   *I grabbed the daily ISO manifest as it's easy for me to grab, you didn't specify installation media so adjust accordingly if necessary*

Comment: hum, I don't find any installation date, but it looks like is has relation with the installed anaconda and some scientific packages:
`./syslog.1:Jan 24 16:30:48 maximeComputer baloo_file.desktop[3489]: 71459803309803538 "/home/maxime/anaconda3/pkgs/scikit-learn-intelex-2021.6.0-py38h06a4308_0/info/licenses/doc" renaming "vmemmap" to "doc"`

Comment: For installation date, I'd look up the `/var/log/apt/history.log`  (and like files if your system is very old & thus it's got numerous older logs too), my normal way of viewing it is with the `view` command, where you can easily search (same keystrokes as any POSIX/unix system; or `vi` etc)